# autocomplete jquery not working with toArray()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to convert list of li's into array using .toArray(), then using this array as source for autocomplete. But it is not working.

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $(function() {

    var availableTags = $("#chem-list li").toArray();

    $( "#s" ).autocomplete({

      source: availableTags

    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you retrieve is an array of DOM elements, while the source option of the autocomplete method expects an array of strings (or plain objects with label and value properties).

So, get those strings from your elements, for example like this:

```
var availableTags = $("#chem-list li").toArray().map(function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
});
```